# Passing String and variables into function

Tags: javascript, string, function, variables

I am using this javascript countdown clock: https://github.com/nikhiln/Circular-Countdown

I have got it working fine but now I am trying to pass in variables into its setup to allow me to control it via buttons.

It is setup via

```
$(".divName").ccountdown(2016,11,24, '10:40');
```

So Instead of that date I want to pass in variables, for example.

```
            var date = new Date();
            var EndTime = new Date(date);
            EndTime.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 50);
            var years = EndTime.getFullYear();
            var months = EndTime.getMonth();
            months = months + 1;
            var days = EndTime.getUTCDate();
            var hours = EndTime.getHours();
            var minutes = ('0'+EndTime.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
            var timeString = " '" + hours + ":" + minutes +"'";
            $(".heatingTimer").ccountdown(years,months,days,timeString);
```

However this approach doesn't work. I am not sure how to pass in the variables in the format that is expeceted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, you only have a typo in your code (or an error), you should pass the time as a string and you are adding extra single quotes, remove the quotes and it should work as expected:

```
var timeString = hours + ":" + minutes;
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought it had to be passed in as '10:42' but it works without the single quotes just fine. Cheers

Comment: That happens, please close this question marking the answer

Comment: @user3473406 Single quotes are the syntax for typing literal strings, they're not actually part of the string data.